# Bootstrap: when checkbox inside label.btn, change event is not working.

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have Bootstrap v3.3 and I have the following `checkbox`es styled as buttons:

```
        <div class="btn-group transactionSheetToolbarStatusToggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft btn btn-default active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">Draft
            </label>
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowFinalised btn btn-default active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">Finalised
            </label>
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowVoid btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">Voided
            </label>
        </div>
```

Using jQuery, I seem to have problem getting the checkbox events.

I have tried:

```
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {...});
```

but it doesn't seem that the event had been triggered.

I have also tried:

```
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {...});
```

but, again, it doesn't seem that the event had been triggered. 
Then I have this:

```
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft').click(function() {...});
```

the event was triggered, but there seems to be something wrong...
The problem appears when I tried to get the `:checked` status of the `checkbox`.

```
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft').click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
        console.log('is checked!');
    } else {
        console.log('not checked...');
    }
});
```

The `:checked` status seems to be opposite! I did some debugging and traced the problem. The reason behind this is that, the `label` was clicked and its `click` event was triggered, the `checkbox` has not been updated yet. Basically the `change` event handler was called before the `checkbox` updated its checked status. 
Being desperate, I came up with the following hack:

```
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft').click(function() {
    var checkbox = $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]');
    setTimeout(function() {
        if (checkbox.is(':checked')) {
            console.log('is checked!');
        } else {
            console.log('not checked...');
        }
    }, 10);
});
```

This seems to work... except that with a `setTimeout` calll to handle the event, it is definitely not a good practice.

So I just want to see if anyone has a better solution to this? Or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: your first try is actually working https://jsfiddle.net/r18r7znv/

Comment: So as I thought.... but I don't know why it doesn't... may be I have missed out some necessary libraries? 
I've made sure I've included the bootstrap css, bootstrap js and jquery js files...

Answer (score 0):

This will trigger checked/Unchecked event.

```js
$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft').on('click','input',function() {
  var checkStatus = ($('input').prop('checked'))? 'is checked!': 'not checked...';
  console.log(checkStatus);
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group transactionSheetToolbarStatusToggle" data-toggle="buttons">
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft btn btn-default active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">Draft
            </label>
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowFinalised btn btn-default active">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off" checked="checked">Finalised
            </label>
            <label class="transactionSheetToolbarShowVoid btn btn-default">
                <input type="checkbox" autocomplete="off">Voided
            </label>
        </div>
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as `$('.transactionSheetToolbarShowDraft input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {...});` ? I have just tried your code, but the event doesn't seem to trigger. Sorry to say. I don't understand why, but the checkbox seems to me that its `checked` status is changed programmatically by bootstrap and thus not triggering any events.